# SQL percentile_cont vs SPSS frequencies percentiles

Tags: sql, spss

I am trying to figure out how percentiles are calculated by SQL's percentile_cont function and by SPSS in FREQUENCIES. I want to compare them and understand why they get different results.

I have tried looking this up myself, but finding a source for this information is difficult. If you have an explanation for why they differ, can you please share where I can read about that myself?

Comment: If you're sure its not an issue of floating point arithmetic, can you please attach a small scale data set that produces different results in  both programs? I tried to recreate this but I always got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The percentile formula used in FREQUENCIES in SPSS Statistics is a weighted average method aimed at p(N+1), where p is the percentile expressed as a proportion (0-1 range) and N is the number of cases or records. Ignoring complications associated with weighted data, particularly non-integer weights, you order the data values in ascending order and if p(N+1) is an integer, you take the value of the p(N+1)th ordered case. If p(N+1) is between the integers associated with the ordinal positions of two numbers, you linearly interpolate between the values according to the fractional value of p(N+1).

This general formula is a commonly-used one, denoted method 4 in SAS and method 6 in a well-known November 1996 article in *The American Statistician* by Hyndman & Fan (Vol. 50, No. 4, pp. 361-365) that is the basis for the nine definitions used in the quantile function in R. There is one special point about the method in FREQUENCIES, which is that while other implementations of this method will set any percentile where p(N+1)>N to the value of the Nth case, in SPSS Statistics the value is given as missing instead.

The method used in SQL's percentile_cont appears to be method 7 in the list of nine from Hyndman & Fan, which aims at 1+(N-1)p. The EXAMINE procedure in SPSS Statistics offers the method used in FREQUENCIES (as the HAVERAGE method) and four additional methods. None of these match the method in SQL's percentile_cont.

Formulas for the statistics in FREQUENCIES, EXAMINE, and other procedures in SPSS Statistics are available in the IBM SPSS Statistics Algorithms manual, a pdf of which is freely downloadable.